# Convert string date time to string datetime in GMT

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have the following datetime `2023-03-03T02:44:54Z` in `Asia/Hong_Kong` time zone. I need to convert it to GMT datetime. I have tried first converting this first to date time

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '2023-03-03T02:44:54Z', 120)
```

But this is producing the following error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: In fact this `2023-03-03T02:44:54Z` is already UTC time, thats what the `Z` means, which is basically the same thing as GMT time. So you don't need to convert anything.

Comment: You will find that your convert works if you use the recommended `datetime2` - one shouldn't be using just `datetime` anymore.

Comment: If you check the [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL) documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) you're probably wanting to use style code `127`. But if keeping track of the actual timezone is important to you then you should be using the `datetimeoffset` data type, i.e.: `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, '2023-03-03T02:44:54Z', 127);`

Comment: @DaleK They are sending Hong Kong time ie: 8 hours ahead of what we want. GMT +8 . We need GMT time ie: -8

Comment: If its Hong Kong time then it shouldn't be formatted with that 'Z' at the end, because that formatting is the standard for UTC time. So either someone has screwed up and is formatting it incorrectly, OR someone knows what they are doing and its already in UTC time.

Comment: @DaleK We cant do anything for that at the moment.

Comment: You could clarify why its being incorrectly formatted surely? Hacking this sort of thing is going to lead to all sorts of system issues later. If you are 100% sure that it shouldn't be UTC time, then strip the Z off. But I would be very very cautious about doing that, because that makes your system very fragile.

Comment: @DaleK i will bring it to their notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to convert your string to a `DATETIME2`, you can use `CAST` or `TRY_CAST` which will convert your string date time to `DATETIME2`.

And then you can specify the ORIGINAL source Time zone and the Target Time Zone.

Below is a sample query to convert UTC to GMT time zone.

```
SELECT CAST( '2023-03-03T02:44:54Z' AS DATETIME2) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time' AS  GMT
```

Comment: You are right, but this is a generic approach you can use any TimeZone and any other string date.

Comment: sure, will do that.

Comment: Nice - and as best practice is to use `datetime2` maybe you can add that as well :)

Comment: They are sending Hong Kong time ie: 8 hours ahead of what we want. GMT +8 . We need GMT time ie: -8 . Will this work for that.

Comment: It should, let me explain how it works. In sql server there is a sys table. 
select * from sys.time_zone_info 
so you need to choose the correct timezone.

Comment: Could probably convert into `datetimeoffset` then straight to `GMT`. Also should probably use `CONVERT` with style 126 https://dbfiddle.uk/CnjP-lKg